# The underlying magic of -webkit-backface-visibility

Tags: html, css, webkit, flicker

I'd like to know why `webkit-backface-visibility` is like that all-purpose aspirin that solves or makes worse all kinds of heterogeneous problems, mostly related to artifacts and flickering.

I have read and understand what really `backface-visibility` is for: It controls wether 3D rotated objects are visible when not facing the screen. There's a nice, straighforward demo [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/)

But I'm curious why, everytime I have strange glitches in the CSS world, **totally unrelated to 3D rotations and their hidden backfaces**, applying `backface-visibility` to the problematic layer or one of its ancestors usually helps or make things worse, but rarely does nothing. I'm talking about things like

- Animations flickering
- Fixed layers Z-Index problems
- Display:none <> visible flicker and artifacts
- Scrolling flicker

Interestingly and always in my humble experience, `backface-visibility:hidden` tends to solve fixed-positioning related stuff, and `backface-visibility:visible` is "best" for flickering. Also interestingly, in Chrome and Safari the side-effects are different, but boy there are!

I am working in a Visual HTML creator, so the situations were I have flicker / artifacts are rather complex (ie. an animation over several layers, a scrolling div behind fixed elements, absolute over fixed with z-index ....)

Anybody can enlighten me?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/M62y2nKZ-gE I found this post on google groups where Chrome graphics engineer Nat Duca says that backface-visibility has some implementation quirks, if this is still interesting to you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of magic you are talking about, but there are certain cases where the **CSS** `backface-visibility` property can help to promote a **DOM** element to a layer so that the browser can take advantage of **GPU** while rendering that element.

**NOTE**: only the `hidden` value will promote to a layer, not `visible`.

Also, there are cases where this property can fix jagged edges around elements – all thanks to **GPU** rendering.

There are a few other **CSS** properties that do the same thing, like `translateZ(0)` or `translate3d(0,0,0)`. These are all hacks, and will be replaced by the new CSS property `will-change`.

If you are doing animations with CSS, the best option in terms of performance is to change only these ***2*** **CSS** properties: `transform` and `opacity`. 
But as browsers are constantly changing, this may also change in the future. The goal is to make every CSS property as smooth as possible (ideally at 60FPS) while animating. I know that the Chrome team is working very hard on this, but not sure about other vendors.

Comment: nice blog post... over this time I've discovered more "webkit backface visiblity" magic, like for instance background-attachment:fixed stopping working if a parent has wbkv:hidden .. I understand now what's going on, but it's amazing the hundred side effects of this tag, and they are different in safari vs chrome, even sometimes one requires backface hidden, and the other backface:vis ... this always talking about very complex pages... will-change seems to help a bit.